# Using the factory method to create a rectangle from points

Tags: dart

Why does the following code not compile?

```
new Rectangle( new Point(-1, -1), new Point( 1, 1));
```

The compiler returns the following

Top-level uncaught error: No constructor 'Rectangle' with matching arguments declared in class 'Rectangle'.

NoSuchMethodError: incorrect number of arguments passed to method named 'Rectangle'
Receiver: Type: class 'Rectangle'
Tried calling: Rectangle(Instance of 'Point', Instance of 'Point')
Found: Rectangle(dynamic, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic): #0      NoSuchMethodError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:156)

Answer (score 4):

The factory constructor you're looking for is `fromPoints`

```
new Rectangle.fromPoints(new Point(-1, -1), new Point( 1, 1));
```

The constructor you're calling, takes 4 values as the left, top, width and height.

Comment: Tried that, the compiler now says Top-level uncaught error: No static method 'fromPoints' declared in class 'Rectangle'. NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'fromPoints' Receiver: Type: class 'Rectang

Comment: You need to invoke this with the "new" keyword.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is

```
new Rectangle.fromPoints( new Point(-1, -1), new Point( 1, 1))
```

Comment: Tried that, the compiler now says
Top-level uncaught error: No static method 'fromPoints' declared in class 'Rectangle'.

NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'fromPoints'
Receiver: Type: class 'Rectangle'

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work

```
new Rectangle.fromPoints( new Point(-1, -1), new Point( 1, 1))
```